# How to modify caption of a wrapped figure?

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I have the following code :

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{tulipmatlab.png}
    \caption{Synthesis tools}
    \end{wrapfigure}
```

Which gives an output of :

[image]

I would like the text to fit better than how it looks now. Maybe remove justification ? How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use `justification=raggedright`, from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3 \textwidth}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{tulipmatlab.png}
\caption{Synthesis tools}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

To have this setting for all `wrapfigure` environments, instead of using `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` inside each `wrapfigure` environment, it's enough to add

```
\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{justification=raggedright}
```

to the preamble.

Comment: Also, is there a way to push it a bit to the right ? Or is the caption location fixed ?

Comment: @NLed you could use `margin=20pt` (or any other length) inside `\captionsetup`: `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,margin=20pt}` Is something like that what you need?

Comment: If you don't want to repeat `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` for every `wrapfigure` you could use `\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{justification=raggedright}` within your document preamble instead. (See `caption` doc, section "wrapfig")

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Yes, I forgot to mention that. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.